# How does SimCSE do dropout twice indepently

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, dropout

How can I pass an input sentence into bert with dropout twice independently?

here is what i try so far, the outputs are identical.

```
bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
sent_dict = tokenizer('Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-cased were not used when initializing BertModel', return_tensors='pt')

bert(**sent_dict).pooler_output == bert(**sent_dict).pooler_output
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot model.train() :(
Dropout only works in training mode